# Django.contrib.auth.login is not working after i redirect to a different url

Tags: django, python-3.x, authentication

The login function is not working , after i call login , authenticated is set 'true' but after i redirect to 'main' view authenticated is set 'false'. How to keep the user logged in even after redirection?

```py
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    user     = forms.CharField()
    password = forms.CharField()


    def login(self):
        try:
            cred = users.objects.get(username = user)
            if password==cred.password):
                return (True, cred)
            return (False, 'Invalid Password.')
        except:
            return (False, 'Not exist')
```

```py
from django.contrib.auth import login as auth_login

def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            valid, message = form.login()
            if valid: 
                auth_login(request, message)
                print(request.user.is_authenticated)
                # this is not working 
                return redirect(main)
            else:
                return redirect(login)
    form = LoginForm()
    args = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'accounts/login.html', args)


def main(request):
    print(request.user.is_authenticated)
```

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't write check your user credentials in form class. Do it in your login view. Example:

```
# views.py
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.urls import reverse
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render

def login_view(request): #changed_the name shouldn't be login
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data["username"]
            password = form.cleaned_data["password"]
            user = authenticate(username, password)
            if user:
                login(user)
                return redirect(reverse("main"))
            else:
                return redirect(reverse("login"))
        form = LoginForm()
        args = {"form": form}
        return render(request, 'accounts/login.html', args)
```

```
# urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    path("login/", views.login_view, name="login"), # <-- really important
    path("main/", views.main_view, name="main")

]
```

To summarize - to redirect to another page use `redirect` function. If you set `name` parameter in url of you view, you can reffer to this view using `reverse`. Also don't reinvent the wheel and write your own authentication function. Django provides: `authenticate(username, password)` and `login(user)` function.